# Visual Studio 2019 IntelliSense Error - false positive - does not exists in the current context

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, intellisense, visual-studio-2019

Composed a fresh Visual Studio 2019 (version info provided at the very end) **ASP.NET Web Application** project (IntelliSense works If I compose **ASP.NET Web Forms Site** project)

[image]

Just written a variable inside `About.aspx.cs` like below

[image: A]

Then used that protected variable in `About.aspx` page like below

[image]

This IntelliSense error also exists in my another computer visual studio 2019 as well. Also it happens in my very big asp.net web application projects as well which I have been using without any problem in previous Visual Studio versions.

Still the project is compiled perfectly fine and working perfectly fine.

[image]

So how can I solve this very annoying problem. Whatever the solution I have tried that I have found on the  Internet failed

```
     I have tried clean > succeeded 
- rebuild > succeeded 
- > restart 
- even deleted vs folder but nope all fails
```

Here version information

```
    Microsoft Visual Studio Enterprise 2019
Version 16.3.8
VisualStudio.16.Release/16.3.8+29503.13
Microsoft .NET Framework
Version 4.8.03761

Installed Version: Enterprise

Architecture Diagrams and Analysis Tools   00435-60000-00000-AA045
Microsoft Architecture Diagrams and Analysis Tools

Visual C++ 2019   00435-60000-00000-AA045
Microsoft Visual C++ 2019

Application Insights Tools for Visual Studio Package   9.1.00913.1
Application Insights Tools for Visual Studio

ASP.NET and Web Tools 2019   16.3.286.43615
ASP.NET and Web Tools 2019

ASP.NET Web Frameworks and Tools 2019   16.3.286.43615
For additional information, visit https://www.asp.net/

Azure App Service Tools v3.0.0   16.3.286.43615
Azure App Service Tools v3.0.0

Azure Functions and Web Jobs Tools   16.3.286.43615
Azure Functions and Web Jobs Tools

C# Tools   3.3.1-beta3-19461-02+2fd12c210e22f7d6245805c60340f6a34af6875b
C# components used in the IDE. Depending on your project type and settings, a different version of the compiler may be used.

Common Azure Tools   1.10
Provides common services for use by Azure Mobile Services and Microsoft Azure Tools.

IntelliCode Extension   1.0
IntelliCode Visual Studio Extension Detailed Info

Microsoft Azure Tools   2.9
Microsoft Azure Tools for Microsoft Visual Studio 0x10 - v2.9.20816.1

Microsoft Continuous Delivery Tools for Visual Studio   0.4
Simplifying the configuration of Azure DevOps pipelines from within the Visual Studio IDE.

Microsoft JVM Debugger   1.0
Provides support for connecting the Visual Studio debugger to JDWP compatible Java Virtual Machines

Microsoft Library Manager   2.0.83+gbc8a4b23ec
Install client-side libraries easily to any web project

Microsoft MI-Based Debugger   1.0
Provides support for connecting Visual Studio to MI compatible debuggers

Microsoft Visual C++ Wizards   1.0
Microsoft Visual C++ Wizards

Microsoft Visual Studio Tools for Containers   1.1
Develop, run, validate your ASP.NET Core applications in the target environment. F5 your application directly into a container with debugging, or CTRL + F5 to edit & refresh your app without having to rebuild the container.

Microsoft Visual Studio VC Package   1.0
Microsoft Visual Studio VC Package

NuGet Package Manager   5.3.1
NuGet Package Manager in Visual Studio. For more information about NuGet, visit https://docs.nuget.org/

ProjectServicesPackage Extension   1.0
ProjectServicesPackage Visual Studio Extension Detailed Info

Snapshot Debugging Extension   1.0
Snapshot Debugging Visual Studio Extension Detailed Info

SQL Server Data Tools   16.0.61908.27190
Microsoft SQL Server Data Tools

TypeScript Tools   16.0.10821.2002
TypeScript Tools for Microsoft Visual Studio

Visual Basic Tools   3.3.1-beta3-19461-02+2fd12c210e22f7d6245805c60340f6a34af6875b
Visual Basic components used in the IDE. Depending on your project type and settings, a different version of the compiler may be used.

Visual F# Tools 10.4 for F# 4.6   16.3.0-beta.19455.1+0422ff293bb2cc722fe5021b85ef50378a9af823
Microsoft Visual F# Tools 10.4 for F# 4.6

Visual Studio Code Debug Adapter Host Package   1.0
Interop layer for hosting Visual Studio Code debug adapters in Visual Studio

Visual Studio Tools for Containers   1.0
Visual Studio Tools for Containers
```

Comment: yes i have tried clean > succeeded - rebuild > succeeded - > restart - even deleted vs folder but nope all fails. Someone on the internet mentioned that if you had installed visual studio 2017 previously, you cant fix until fresh windows 10 installation. Can this be true?

Comment: i have deleted obj, bin, vs folder then did clean and rebuild again, this time seems like working finally

Comment: Hi friend, thanks for your sharing and please mark your reply as answer and that will help other community members who easier search this useful information, it just a reminder :) See [can I answer my...](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer)